# Python turtle get tkinter root

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Python turtle works with tkinter. How to get the `root` you know from tkinter?
Like this:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

but for turtle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top-level widget is available through the `winfo_toplevel` method of the turtle canvas:

```
import turtle

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
```

It is of a subtype of `Tk`:

```
import tkinter

assert type(root) is turtle._Root
assert isinstance(root, tkinter.Tk)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! Very interesting that there are people with 5k rep using turtle / having knowledge using it.

Comment: Actually, I found your question while researching for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50657029/674064). :-) That's also how I noticed your answer was wrong: I couldn't call `turtle.getcanvas().protocol()`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [@das-g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674064/das-g)

```py
root = turtle.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
```

gives you an object representing the turtle root window.

---

However, if your use case is to integrate turtle graphics with a full-blown Tkinter application, the explicit approach **should be preferred** at all times:

```py
from tkinter import *
import turtle

root = Tk()
turtle_canvas = turtle.Canvas(root)
turtle_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True) # fill the entire window

protagonist = turtle.RawTurtle(turtle_canvas)
protagonist.fd(100) # etc.
```

<sup>This adds the extra benefit of being able to control position and size of the turtle canvas. Plus, having explicit code helps others understanding it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
turtle.getcanvas()
```

returns the object you are (I am) looking for.

Comment: That returns the canvas, which _isn't_ the top-level widget: `assert not isinstance(turtle.getcanvas(), tkinter.Tk)`.