# Make my turtle-based game exit button work

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to make an *exit* button in my code, but it won't work. I would prefer to use `exit()` but if it is not possible with `exit()` then you could use an other way to make it work. Also please explain to me how you fixed it -- thanks in advance! My code:

```
import turtle
import math
import random

screen = turtle.Screen()
width = 780
height = 630
screen.setup(width, height)
screen.bgcolor("#202020")
screen.title("SpaceWar")

border = turtle.Turtle()
border.color("white")
border.speed(0)
border.penup()
border.setposition(-375, -300)
border.pendown()
border.pensize(3)
for side in range(2):
    border.forward(750)
    border.left(90)
    border.forward(600)
    border.left(90)
border.hideturtle()

score = 0
text1 = turtle.Turtle()
text1.color("white")
text1.speed(0)
text1.penup()
text1.hideturtle()
text1.setposition(-30, 200)
text1.write("Score: ", False, font=("Arial", 50, "normal"), align="center")

text2 = turtle.Turtle()
text2.color("white")
text2.speed(0)
text2.hideturtle()

text3 = turtle.Turtle()
text3.color("red")
text3.speed(0)
text3.hideturtle()

text4 = turtle.Turtle()
text4.color("blue")
text4.speed(0)
text4.hideturtle()

button = turtle.Turtle()
button.color("white")
button.speed(0)
button.pensize(4)
button.penup()
button.hideturtle()

button_text = turtle.Turtle()
button_text.color("white")
button_text.speed(0)
button_text.penup()
button_text.hideturtle()

booster1 = turtle.Turtle()
booster1.shape("circle")
booster1.color("#1c77d9")
booster1.penup()
booster1.speed(0)
booster1.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

booster2 = turtle.Turtle()
booster2.shape("circle")
booster2.color("#d6281c")
booster2.penup()
booster2.speed(0)
booster2.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

decreaser = turtle.Turtle()
decreaser.shape("circle")
decreaser.color("green")
decreaser.penup()
decreaser.speed(0)
decreaser.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

speed1 = 3
speed2 = 3

player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.shape("triangle")
player1.color("#1c77d9")
player1.shapesize(1.5)
player1.speed(0)
player1.penup()
player1.goto(-330, 0)

def forward():
    player1.fd(speed1)
    player2.fd(speed2)

def turn_right():
    player1.rt(45)

def turn_left():
    player1.lt(45)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(turn_left, "a")
turtle.onkeypress(turn_right, "d")

player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player2.shape("triangle")
player2.color("#d6281c")
player2.shapesize(1.5)
player2.speed(0)
player2.penup()
player2.setheading(180)
player2.goto(330, 0)

def turn_right2():
    player2.rt(45)

def turn_left2():
    player2.lt(45)

def exit_button():
    for i in range(2):
        button.forward(300)
        button.left(90)
        button.forward(100)
        button.left(90)

def button_click(x, y):
    if x > -150 and x < 150 and y > -100 and y < 0:
        exit()

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(turn_left2, "Left")
turtle.onkey(turn_right2, "Right")

while True:
    forward()

    a = math.sqrt(math.pow(player1.xcor()-player2.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player1.ycor()-player2.ycor(), 2))
    b = math.sqrt(math.pow(player1.xcor()-booster1.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player1.ycor()-booster1.ycor(), 2))
    c = math.sqrt(math.pow(player2.xcor()-booster2.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player2.ycor()-booster2.ycor(), 2))
    d = math.sqrt(math.pow(player1.xcor()-decreaser.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player1.ycor()-decreaser.ycor(), 2))
    e = math.sqrt(math.pow(player2.xcor()-decreaser.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(player2.ycor()-decreaser.ycor(), 2))

    if a < 20:
        player1.setposition(-330, 0)
        player1.setheading(0)
        player2.setposition(330, 0)
        player2.setheading(180)
        score += 1
        text2.undo()
        text2.hideturtle()
        text2.penup()
        text2.setposition(70, 200)
        scorestring = "%s" %score
        text2.write(scorestring, False, font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))

    if b < 20:
        speed1 += 1
        booster1.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

    if c < 20:
        speed2 += 1
        booster2.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

    if d < 20:
        speed1 -= 1
        decreaser.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

    if e < 20:
        speed2 -= 1
        decreaser.setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

    if speed1 == 7:
        speed1 -= 1

    if speed2 == 7:
        speed2 -= 1

    if player1.xcor() > 375 or player1.xcor() < -375:
        score += 1
        player1.setposition(-330, 0)
        player1.setheading(0)
        text2.undo()
        text2.hideturtle()
        text2.penup()
        text2.setposition(70, 200)
        scorestring = "%s" %score
        text2.write(scorestring, False, font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))

    if player1.ycor() > 300 or player1.ycor() < -300:
        score += 1
        player1.setposition(-330, 0)
        player1.setheading(0)
        text2.undo()
        text2.hideturtle()
        text2.penup()
        text2.setposition(70, 200)
        scorestring = "%s" %score
        text2.write(scorestring, False, font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))

    if player2.xcor() > 375 or player2.xcor() < -375:
        player2.right(180)

    if player2.ycor() > 300 or player2.ycor() < -300:
        player2.right(180)

    if score == 2:
        text3.write("Red Won!", False, font=("Arial", 70, "normal"), align="center")
        button_text.goto(-85, -100)
        button_text.write("Exit", False, font=("Arial", 70, "normal"))
        button.goto(-150, -100)
        button.pendown()

        booster1.hideturtle()
        booster2.hideturtle()
        decreaser.hideturtle()
        player1.hideturtle()
        player2.hideturtle()

        exit_button()

        turtle.listen()
        turtle.onscreenclick(button_click, 1)
```

Comment: The OS window already has a close button on it, is this ok for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654793/how-to-detect-x-close-button-in-python-turtle-graphics

Comment: Please take a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Your question should contain a clear problem description, which ideally contains a *minimal* code example to reproduce your problem. Please avoid adding code via links or images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you didn't `break` out of the `while True:` loop once you setup the exit button (moving on to a `mainloop()` call).  Below is my rework of your code that fixes this problem and addresses a number of other issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import sqrt
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 780, 630

SMALL_FONT = ('Arial', 25, 'normal')
LARGE_FONT_SIZE = 70
LARGE_FONT = ('Arial', LARGE_FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

def forward():
    player1.fd(speed1)
    player2.fd(speed2)

def turn_right():
    player1.rt(45)

def turn_left():
    player1.lt(45)

def turn_right2():
    player2.rt(45)

def turn_left2():
    player2.lt(45)

def button_click(x, y):
    if -150 < x < 150 and -100 < y < 0:
        exit()

def exit_button():
    button.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        button.forward(300)
        button.left(90)
        button.forward(100)
        button.left(90)

    button.end_fill()

    button_text.write("Exit", align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)

    screen.onscreenclick(button_click)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('#202020')
screen.title("SpaceWar")

border = Turtle()
border.hideturtle()
border.color('white')
border.speed('fastest')
border.pensize(3)

border.penup()
border.setposition(15 - WIDTH/2 - 4, 15 - HEIGHT/2 + 4)  # 4 = adjustment for "chrome"
border.pendown()

for side in range(2):
    border.forward(WIDTH - 30)
    border.left(90)
    border.forward(HEIGHT - 30)
    border.left(90)

score = 0

text2 = Turtle()
text2.hideturtle()
text2.color('white')
text2.penup()
text2.setposition(70, 200)
scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
text2.write(scorestring, align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)

text3 = Turtle()
text3.hideturtle()
text3.color('red')

button = Turtle()
button.hideturtle()
button.color('white')
button.speed('fastest')
button.pensize(4)
button.penup()
button.goto(-150, -100)

button_text = Turtle()
button_text.hideturtle()
button_text.penup()
button_text.goto(0, -50 + -LARGE_FONT_SIZE/2)

booster1 = Turtle()
booster1.shape('circle')
booster1.color('#1c77d9')
booster1.speed('fastest')
booster1.penup()
booster1.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

booster2 = Turtle()
booster2.shape('circle')
booster2.color('#d6281c')
booster2.speed('fastest')
booster2.penup()
booster2.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

decreaser = Turtle()
decreaser.shape('circle')
decreaser.color('green')
decreaser.speed('fastest')
decreaser.penup()
decreaser.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

speed1 = 3
speed2 = 3

player1 = Turtle()
player1.shape('triangle')
player1.color('#1c77d9')
player1.shapesize(1.5)
player1.speed('fastest')
player1.penup()
player1.setx(-330)

player2 = Turtle()
player2.shape('triangle')
player2.color('#d6281c')
player2.shapesize(1.5)
player2.speed('fastest')
player2.penup()
player2.setheading(180)
player2.setx(330)

screen.onkeypress(turn_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(turn_right, 'd')
screen.onkey(turn_left2, 'Left')
screen.onkey(turn_right2, 'Right')
screen.listen()

while True:
    forward()

    a = sqrt(pow(player1.xcor() - player2.xcor(), 2) + pow(player1.ycor() - player2.ycor(), 2))
    b = sqrt(pow(player1.xcor() - booster1.xcor(), 2) + pow(player1.ycor() - booster1.ycor(), 2))
    c = sqrt(pow(player2.xcor() - booster2.xcor(), 2) + pow(player2.ycor() - booster2.ycor(), 2))
    d = sqrt(pow(player1.xcor() - decreaser.xcor(), 2) + pow(player1.ycor() - decreaser.ycor(), 2))
    e = sqrt(pow(player2.xcor() - decreaser.xcor(), 2) + pow(player2.ycor() - decreaser.ycor(), 2))

    if a < 20:
        player1.setx(-330)
        player1.setheading(0)
        player2.setx(330)
        player2.setheading(180)
        score += 1
        text2.undo()
        scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
        text2.write(scorestring, align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)

    if b < 20:
        speed1 += 1
        booster1.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

    if c < 20:
        speed2 += 1
        booster2.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

    if d < 20:
        speed1 -= 1
        decreaser.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

    if e < 20:
        speed2 -= 1
        decreaser.setposition(randint(-250, 250), randint(-250, 250))

    if speed1 == 7:
        speed1 -= 1

    if speed2 == 7:
        speed2 -= 1

    if not -375 <= player1.xcor() <= 375:
        score += 1
        player1.setx(-330)
        player1.setheading(0)
        text2.undo()
        scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
        text2.write(scorestring, align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)

    if not -300 <= player1.ycor() <= 300:
        score += 1
        player1.setx(-330)
        player1.setheading(0)
        text2.undo()
        scorestring = "Score: %s" % score
        text2.write(scorestring, align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)

    if not -375 <= player2.xcor() <= 375:
        player2.right(180)

    if not -300 <= player2.ycor() <= 300:
        player2.right(180)

    if score == 2:
        text3.write("Red Won!", align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)

        booster1.hideturtle()
        booster2.hideturtle()
        decreaser.hideturtle()
        player1.hideturtle()
        player2.hideturtle()

        exit_button()

        break

screen.mainloop()
```

I hope this gives you some useful ideas.  The next thing I'd do is eliminate the `while True:` call, which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle, and make the body of it a function invoked by `ontimer()`.